# No payload received by NestJS endpoint when running inside Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, express, nestjs

I'm encountering an issue with my NestJS application where no payload is being received by an endpoint when the application is running inside a Docker container. The endpoint is expected to receive data from the client, but when the application is running in the Docker container, the payload appears to be missing.

When I run the NestJS application using npm run start:dev, the endpoint works as expected, and the payload is received correctly. However, when I run the application inside a Docker container, the payload is not received by the endpoint.

Here's a simplified version of the controller method:

```
@Get('signedUrl/:fileCategory/:fileName')
@HttpCode(200)
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
getSignedUrl(@Param() request: GetFileRequest): Promise<GetFileResponse> {
 console.log("Request",request)//getting undefined here
  }
```

Request that i made:

```
curl -X GET http://0.0.0.0:3300/api/file/signedurl/PROFILE_IMAGE/fileName.jpg
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine 
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./

COPY ./.env ./
COPY ./.docker.env ./

RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


ENV ENV_FILE .docker.env

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

docker-compose-dev.yml

```
version: '3'
  services:
    file-upload-service:
       build: ./file-upload-service/
       ports:
          - "3300:80"
       container_name: file-upload-service
       networks:
       - foo-network
networks:
 foo-network :
    external: true
```

Commands used to run container:

```
 docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml  up --build file-upload-service
```

It's worth noting that this setup was working fine a few days ago, and no specific changes were made to the Docker configuration. Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to receive payload data at the endpoint when running my NestJS application inside a Docker container.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using docker compose file to run docker containers or using docker commands? If any please add them to the question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.I added that in the question.

Comment: Maybe there is already something running on port 3300?

Comment: No. I confirmed that. Basically app runs without any fail. I checked with different endpoint without payload thats working. Only problem is payload is not passed form client to backend. But when i run outside docker no issue at all.

Comment: Try upgrading `reflect-metadata` to `0.2.1` and rebuilding the container ignoring the cache to ensure the correct reflect-metadata is downloaded and used

Comment: @JayMcDoniel OMG! That was the issue. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely there were two conflicting versions of `reflect-metadata` installed in the docker container. This could be confirmed locally by using your package manager of choice's `list` command to find all the `reflect-metadata` installs and verifying only a single version exists. As TypeORM recently updated their version to `0.2.1` and Nest is compatible with it (but by default has `0.1.14` installed) this can usually be remedied by running your package manager's `install` command with `reflect-metadata@0.2.1`. In this case, the docker container will also need to be rebuilt without cache to ensure that only the latest packages are used.